# allocating memory for class member

Tags: c++, memory

I'm trying to provide a uniform interface for two similar types, one dealing with `double`s and the other with `float`s.

```
class float_type {
  float_type() { /* does floaty stuff */ }
  float f();
};
class double_type {
  double_type() { /* does doubly stuff */ }
  double f();
};
```

I want to write a class that allocates one or the other depending on what the program needs to do.
I'm perfectly fine with the result of `float_type::f()` being converted to double. In fact, it happens anyway.
I tried to write it like this:

```
class union_type {
  bool is_double;
  char mem[ sizeof(double_type) > sizeof(float_type)
          ? sizeof(double_type) : sizeof(float_type) ];
public:
  float_or_double_value_reader(bool is_double)
  : is_double(is_double)
  {
    if (is_double) new(mem) double_type();
    else new(mem) float_type();
  }

  ~float_or_double_value_reader() {
    if (is_double) delete static_cast<double_type*>(mem);
    else           delete static_cast< float_type*>(mem);
  }

  double f() {
    return (is_doubled
      ? static_cast<double_type*>(mem)->f()
      : static_cast< float_type*>(mem)->f()
    );
  }
};
```

But I get `invalid static_cast from type 'char [128]' to type 'double_type'`.

I know I could add a member pointers to point to what `new` returns,
but that would be redundant, since I already know where `mem` is located,
so I want to avoid that.

If I use `reinterpret_cast` instead, I get `free(): invalid pointer:` at runtime when the `union_type` is destroyed.

What's the appropriate method of casting here?

Comment: Is `data` supposed to be `mem`? Anyway, when you use placement new, you don't use `delete` on the object, because that will try to deallocate memory.  Instead, explicitly call the appropriate destructor (like `reinterpret_cast<double_type*>(data)->~double_type();`)

Comment: Yes, `data` is `mem`. Apologies for inconsistency. Let me fix it.

Comment: @ChristopherOicles Thanks. I was not aware of that. Could you write that as an answer?

Comment: Go ahead and accept immibis' answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reinterpret_cast` should be the appropriate method of casting.

However, you can't simply `delete reinterpret_cast<double_type*>(mem)` because that will not only destroy the object, but also free the memory as if it was allocated with `new` - which it wasn't.

You can use `reinterpret_cast<double_type*>(mem)->~double_type();` to destroy the object without attempting to free the memory.

Of course the above applies to `float_type` as well.

Answer (score 0):

A better option would be to provide casting operator.

I would have provided a implicit `double` casting operator to the float class to achieve the same interface

Comment: That would work in some cases, but in my case, the constructors of `float_type` and `double_type` do different things, and I need to call one or the other, but not both. Dynamic allocation is of course an option, but why no do it statically?

Comment: In that case a better option would be to prefer composition over inheritance for a cleaner interface

Answer (score 0):

You could use a template base class:

```
#include <iostream>

template < typename T >
class base_decimal
{
    public:
        base_decimal(T data) : _data(data) {}
        virtual ~base_decimal() {}
        T f() { return this->_data; }
        base_decimal& operator=(T val) { this->_data = val; }
        operator T() { return this->_data; }
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const base_decimal& bd)
        {
            os << bd._data;
            return os;
        }
    private:
        T _data;
};

class float_type : public base_decimal<float>
{
    public:
        float_type(float f) : base_decimal<float>(f)
        {
            // do float stuff
        }
};

class double_type : public base_decimal<double>
{
    public:
        double_type(double d) : base_decimal<double>(d)
        {
            // do double stuff
        }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    float_type f = 1.2f;
    double_type d = 2.2;

    std::cout << "f = " << f << std::endl;
    std::cout << "d = " << d << std::endl;

    double rd = d;
    double rf = f;

    std::cout << "rf = " << rf << std::endl;
    std::cout << "rd = " << rd << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This would definitely be applicable in a different situation, but I needed to construct one or the other (not both) for a given constructor argument. And the two types are from a library in my case, and I have no control of them.